# Understand how run React and Node.js application

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am creating my first application using `React` and `node.js` in `vscode`. I have few questions on how to make them work together

1. When I create the `React` application, I run it using `react-scripts start`. Does this start a web server?
2. When I create the `node` application, I run it using `nodemon ./bin/www` or `node ./bin/www`. Does it also start a web server?
3. What I observed is that they both start their respective applications on `localhost:3000`. This creates a conflict of ports and only one survives. Do I need to change port of one of them to make them run simultaneously?
4. In production, would I have to do the same?
5. Is it better that instead of using `react`, I use the inbuilt support of views (using `.ejs`. or `pug`) in `node`. I am finding balance between cost of running the application in production (2 web servers) and load balancing

Comment: I recommend u to just use NextJS since it has everything done up for you, and easy to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I create the React application, I run it using react-scripts start. Does this start a web server?

Yes

> When I create the node application, I run it using nodemon ./bin/www or node ./bin/www. Does it also start a web server?

Yes

> What I observed is that they both start their respective applications on localhost:3000. This creates a conflict of ports and only one survives. Do I need to change port of one of them to make them run simultaneously?

Yes

> In production, would I have to do the same?

You cannot host a react application or an API without having a webserver, but which webserver you use in production is probably going to be different from your development environment. There's a number of different ways to deploy applications.

> Is it better that instead of using react, I use the inbuilt support of views (using .ejs. or pug) in node. I am finding balance between cost of running the application in production (2 web servers) and load balancing

If simple `.ejs` files suffice for your use-case (you're building a website, not a complex web application) then I would say you should take the simple approach.

It's true that deploying a React application + a Node API is going to be marginally more complicated, but that cost will be in how much you need to learn and understand, and should probably not affect hosting cost.